# Supppose $ f : X \rightarrow Y $ is a function and $ A \subseteq X $ is countable. Then $ f(A) $ is countable.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Supppose $ f : X \rightarrow Y $ is a function and $ A \subseteq X $ is countable. Then $ f(A) $ is countable.

I am in an introduction to proofs course... we are studying topology in order to use that to write proofs. I have had a very brief introduction to countable sets and must show this statement is either true and prove it or show that it is false and give a counter example.
For proving a set is countable I know you need to show it is finite or countably infinite but I am still vague on how to do that...

Comment: What is your exact definition of "countable"? There are several equivalent ones (as well as some that are not), and the precise proof you need depends on which of the definitions you're aiming at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f$ to be a function, each $x \in A$ can get mapped to *at most* one value in the range of $f$. For each $y$ in the range of $f$, $y$ corresponds to *at least* one $x \in A$. You should be able to infer (or easily prove) from this realization that $|f(A)| \leq |A|.$ So $f(A)$.

As for you being vague on the nature of countability, here is some more info. A set $C$ is countable iff it has a one-to-one correspondence with a subset of the natural numbers. That is, for some $N \subset \Bbb{N}$ there exists a bijection $g:N \to C$ such that $g(n) = c_n \in C$ for each $n \in N$. The entire definition of countable is most often written in the condensed form of $C = \{c_1,c_2,c_3,\ldots \}$ or $C = \{c_i\}_{i \in \Bbb{N}}$. However, under this definition of countable, sets that are finite *or* countably infinite are all considered countable, since $N$ doesn't have to be a proper subset of $\Bbb{N}$. However, it is often the case that when one is given "a countable set" in a theorem, it is implied to be countably infinite, and not finite. So the definition is a bit ambiguous in practice.

Anyway, with the proof that you are given, you are allowed to assume that $A$ is numerable, so you can write $A = \{a_1,a_2, a_3, \ldots \}$. You want to show that $f(A)$ can be written as a numerable set in the form $\{f(a_1),f(a_2),f(a_3)\ldots \}$. See if you can combine the definition of countable with what I said in my first paragraph, and perhaps use some of the things other users have answered with. It might help if for practice you first prove

> If $A\subset X$ is finite and $f$ is a function from $X \to Y$ then $f(A)$ is finite.

Once you prove this, you may have an easier time proving this result for when $A$ is countably infinite.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not entirely accurate. For instance, suppose $A\subseteq X$ countable and we define $f(x):=y$ with $y\in Y$ fix.

So, the statement should be

> Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a function, and let $A\subseteq X$ be a countable set. Then $f(A)$ is *at most* countable. (At most countable is equivalent to finite or countable.)

You can prove before the follow statements:

**Proposition 1.** Let $Y$ be a set, and let $f\colon\mathbf N\to Y$ be a function. Then $f(\mathbf N)$ is at most countable.

**Corollary 2.** Let $X$ be a countable set, and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a function. Then $f(X)$ is at most countable.

Now, you can prove your statement by Corollary 2 and the restriccion $f|_A$.

**Hint.** In the Proposition 1, the basic problem is that is not assumed to be one-to-one. Define $A$ to be the set $$A:=\{n\in\mathbf N:f(m)\ne f(n)\;\text{for all}\;0\le m\le n\};$$ informally speaking, $A$ is the set of natural numbers $n$ for which $f(n)$ does not appear in the sequence $f(0),f(1),\dotsc,f(n-1)$. Prove that when $f$ is restricted to $A$, it becomes a bijection from $A$ to $f(\mathbf N)$. The use the proposition

**Proposition 0.** Let $X$ be an infinite subset of the natural numbers $\mathbf N$. Then there exists a unique bijection $f\colon\mathbf N\to X$ which is increasing, in the sense $f(n+1)>f(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbf N$. In particular, $X$ has equal cardinality with $\mathbf N$ and is hence countable.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is countable. We can number the elements of $A$, and call them $x_n$. We have

$$A = \left\lbrace x_n : n\in \mathbb{N} \right\rbrace $$

Then

$$f(A) = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left\lbrace f(x_n) \right\rbrace = \left\lbrace y_n = f(x_n) : n\in\mathbb{N} \right\rbrace  $$

And $n\mapsto y_n$ is then obvisoulsly a surjection from $\mathbb{N}\to f(A)$

Answer (score 0):

Use the following definition for countability:

> A non empty set $A$ is **countable** if there is a surjection $\varphi:\Bbb N\to A$.

Suppose that $A$ is countable and $\varphi:\Bbb N\to A$ is the surjection. Define a map $\psi:A\to f(A)$ by $\psi(x)=f(x)$. Then clearly $\psi$ is a surjection. Now define $g:\Bbb N\to f(A)$ by $g=\psi\circ\varphi$. Since composition of two surjection is again a surjection, it follows that $g$ is a surjection and hence $f(A)$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \{ x_n \}_n$. Then you have $f(A) = \{ f(x_n) \}_n$.

Define $\phi: f(A) \to \mathbb{N}$ by $\phi(f(x_n)) = \min \{ k | f(x_k) = f(x_n) \}$. It is easy to check that $\phi$ is injective.

Let $I = \phi(f(A)) \subset \mathbb{N}$.

If $I$ is finite, you are finished, otherwise $I$ is infinite. Since $I \subset \mathbb{N}$, we can order the elements in increasing order to get
$I = \{k_1,k_2,... \}$. Note that the map $\eta:\mathbb{N} \to I$ given by $\eta(i) = k_i$ is a bijection.

Then $\eta^{-1} \circ \phi$ is a bijection between $f(A)$ and $\mathbb{N}$.